# How to inject a service in a Razor file properly?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, blazor

I have created some services with interfaces and added them as services the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs file (see screenshot and code).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            EstablishDbContext(services, "DevelopmentConnection");
            AddVOMApi(services, "AuthorizationStringsDevelopment");
        }
        else
        {
            EstablishDbContext(services, "ProductionConnection");
            AddVOMApi(services, "AuthorizationStringsProduction");
            throw new NotImplementedException("The production environment has not been implemented.");
        }

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();   
        services.AddTransient<VomConnection, VomConnection>();
        services.AddTransient<IImportInternalHelper, ImportInternalHelper>();

    }
```

When I want to inject the services in a Razor file, my IDE (Jetbrains Rider) adds the @using statements with the path to the classes.

```
@using Presentation.WebUI.Shared.Components
@using Presentation.WebUI.Shared.Components.Tables
@using Infrastructure.AdapterService.VOM
@using Application.HelperClasses
@inject VomConnection _Vom;
@inject IImportInternalHelper _helper;
```

In the documentation for Blazor it looks like you do not have to use @using when injecting a service, @inject should be enough.

My code works, but what is wrong with my code since I need to use both @inject and @using? I cannot inject without @using.

```
@using Presentation.WebUI.Shared.Components
@using Presentation.WebUI.Shared.Components.Tables
@*@using Infrastructure.AdapterService.VOM
@using Application.HelperClasses*@
@inject VomConnection _Vom;
@inject IImportInternalHelper _helper;
```

[Service added in Startup.cs file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBSOM.png)

[My injections + @ using. It works but does not look right, compared to Blazor documentation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGyG0.png)

[When deleting @using the injections does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuPnO.png)

I have tried to inject in different ways but the IDE always adds the @using part.

Comment: Please add codes as text

Answer (score 2):

`@using` is used to specify to the razor file that you will use a namespace.
It is just used to simplify your code, you can inject your service directly with the full namespace path if you want.

If you don't want to add it to all your razor files, but you use a specific namespace everywhere, you can add it in `_Imports.razor`.

However, do not import recklessly all the namespaces in `_Imports.razor` this goes against the principle of namespaces and can lead to name conflicts.

[Blazor project structure Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/project-structure?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

`@using` used to introduce the namespace of the class(your service) you'd like to inject in your components.

Answer (score 0):

> My code works, but what is wrong with my code since I need to use both @inject and @using? I cannot inject without @using.

The `usings` are added by your IDE because the component class you're injecting the service into, needs to know where to find the service object.  By default namespaces mirror directory structures.  The service is in a different directory to your component, therefore a different namespace.

As already said in other answers, you can add the namespace to the _Imports.razor file to make the namespace available globally within the project.

Your namespaces don't need to follow your directory structure.  In many projects they don't.

Take a look at this project at the other end of the scale:

[image]

All the objects within this library are defined in the `Blazr.App.Core`.

Here's `WeatherForecastsViewService`.  Note the namespace declaration.

```cs
namespace Blazr.App.Core;

public class WeatherForecastsViewService
{
 //....
}
```

You can do the same with components

```cs
@namespace Blazr.App.Components;
```